# jQuery validate style parent div for checkboxes/radios only

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-validate

I am working with jQuery validate and am trying to setup styling for error state radio and checkboxes.

As I cannot change the radio button itself, this is what I am using at the moment which targets all fields in myform and, if they error, it changes the background colour of text, textarea, select etc and it also adds a border to the parent div (this is how I notify error for radio and checkboxes).

The problem is I only want to do add the border to the parent div of radio buttons and checkboxes but not for text, textarea and select boxes. How can I do that?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myform").validate({
        highlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent('div').addClass("parent-error");
            $(element).addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            $(element).parent('div').removeClass("parent-error");
            $(element).removeClass("error");
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5L74Lvzt/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out using

```
if ($(element).is(':radio') || $(element).is(':checkbox')) {
```

which made the code I use:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".myform").validate({
        highlight: function (element) {
            if ($(element).is(':radio') || $(element).is(':checkbox')) {
                $(element).parent('div').addClass("parent-error");
            }
            $(element).addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function (element) {
            if ($(element).is(':radio') || $(element).is(':checkbox')) {
                $(element).parent('div').removeClass("parent-error");
            }
            $(element).removeClass("error");
        }
    });
});
```